# Play! Framework Templating Engine issues importing long class names

Tags: scala, playframework, template-engine, playframework-2.2

I've got a List of classes I want to send down to a Scala Template in Play! Framework 2.2.3
however I ran into some issues while trying to do so.

The class I want the list to contain is an arbitrary class type that comes from a package outside of my workspace, but not natively from Java. See the picture below.

Note: I do not have a project/Build.scala file.

[image: First row in the Play! Template]

The above image represents the first line in my scala template, I have tried to use @import as well (`@import com.***.***.type._`, `com.***.***.type.Version`, etc) but to no avail.

This is the error message given to me by Play! Framework.
[image: The error message displayed while running the Server]

Is there an issue with the namespacing? Everything works fine when using classes located in my workspace.

The Paths are correct, I've double checked that. For reasons I cannot disclose more code in this region, if more information is required please ask for it and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to package named **type**. This word is reserved in Scala as language keyword. You need to escape it like this:

```
@import List[com.your.package.`type`.Version]
```